# Return an array of a number and its square in python

Tags: python, list, function, numpy

How do I create an array of 1:100 numbers that contains the number and its square?

The function would return the result of in python:

```
x1= np.array([[1,1],
        [2,4],
        [3,9],
        [4,16],
        [5,25]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) to generate numbers from 1 to 100. And [`np.power`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.power.html) to squaring here we use [`np.power`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.power.html) which gives more flexibility. Then use [`np.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) to weave them together.

```
nums = np.arange(1, 101)
np.column_stack((nums, np.power(nums, 2)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer `arange` and `c_`:

```
nums = np.arange(1, 101)
np.c_[nums, nums ** 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

result = np.asarray([[x,x*x] for x in range(1, 101)])
```